# Searching for a specific sequence in a column full of random numbers (Excel)

Tags: excel, sequence, vba

I have a column with numbers arranged randomly eg.

```
range("a1:a30") = [1 48 8 93 6 2 5 1 7 43 ***10 1 300*** 4 2 5 1 11 2 3 1 3 2 1 1 3 2 6 5 4]
```

In this data I would like to find a sequence `10 1 300` and highlight it. Sequence such as `300 10 1` or `10 300 1` should not be highlighted.

I tried using `find`, `conditional formatting` and `match` but nothing works. All These functions that I tried, return a single value and not a sequence. In reality the actual data is 20000 lines long and I cannot use visual inspection to find the required sequence.

EDIT: Changed the sequence from `1 2 3` to `10 1 300`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub FindSequence()

    Dim rng As Range
    Dim lRow As Long 'the last row in column A with data
    Dim cRow As Long 'the current row for the loop below
    Dim sRow As Long 'start row of your sequence
    Dim eRow As Long 'end row of your saequence

    With Sheets("Data")
        lRow = Sheets("Data").Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    End With

    For cRow = 1 To lRow
        If Cells(cRow, 1).Value = 1 Then
            If Cells(cRow + 1, 1).Value = 2 Then
                If Cells(cRow + 2, 1).Value = 3 Then
                    sRow = cRow
                    eRow = cRow + 2
                    Sheets("Data").Range(Cells(sRow, 1), Cells(eRow, 1)).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next cRow

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you @EarlyBird2. Works perfect!

Comment: Great- no problem :-)

Comment: Just one last question. What changes are needed in the code if I have to find the sequence `57 1 DF`. A combination of Alpha numeric kind of sequence. Because the code mentioned above works for only numeric values

Comment: `If Cells(cRow, 1).Value = 57 Then
            If Cells(cRow + 1, 1).Value = 1 Then
                If Cells(cRow + 2, 1).Value = "DF" Then
                    sRow = cRow
                    eRow = cRow + 2
                    Sheets("Data").Range(Cells(sRow, 1), Cells(eRow, 1)).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
                End If
            End If
        End If`

Answer (score 0):

Insert two bank rows at the top, clear any formatting from and select ColumnA then HOME > Styles - Conditional Formatting, New Rule..., *Use a formula to determine which cells to format* and **Format values where this formula is true:**:

```
=OR((A1048575=10)*(A1048576=1)*(A1=300),(A1048576=10)*(A1=1)*(A2=300),(A1=10)*(A2=1)*(A3=300))
```

<kbd>Format...</kbd>, select choice of formatting, <kbd>OK</kbd>, <kbd>OK</kbd>.

Comment: the formula you stated contains an error and I get an error message saying that 'The formula you entered contains an error'. I don't know which version of excel you are using but I am using Excel 2010 so may be they have changed the Syntax.

Comment: It only highlights the first value `1`. Does not highlight the next two values after that.